# Rechargeable battery configuration for 5V

Tags: voltage-regulator, boost, buck, efficiency

I have 6x 18650 (3.7v) cells.
I'm trying to build basic power-bank and wondering what battery configuration would
be better for minimizing power loss in voltage regulation/conversion process?

Edit:
Expected load will be less than 1A (at 5V output).

Comment: How much current does your load need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, resistance is the main reason for power loss, where the power lost is proportional to the current squared for a given resistance. This includes the internal resistance of the cells themselves, as well as the resistance in your wiring and your power conversion circuit elements.

So, in general, when you have a choice, select a configuration that uses higher voltages and lower currents wherever possible. This would mean putting the cells in series and using a switchmode buck regulator to power your load.